# closing connections within a using block

Tags: c#, coding-style, idisposable

On reading lots of code, I find that a given `Connection` object, which implements `IDisposable`, is is manually closed within a `using` statement. I see this when I see code related to MySQL.

It's not needed to be explicitly closed. Why would the developer close it manually?

```
using(cnn)
{
    //code is here
    cnn.close();
}
```

Is this a good/helpful measure?

Comment: Please use the "code" button to mark your code as code next time, it improves the readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicitly closing in a `using` block is **duplication, misleading and redundant** so for me, is a **bad** thing.

Comment: What if you need to do multiple selects and inserts with heavy business logic in between?

Comment: I would not do anything differently. Why would it be different? In "any" using block, I would never call Dispose(), regardless of the object.

Comment: Well you would call close. And like I said, it is not guaranteed that Close is called in the dispose. Especially in any third party library. If I were to write a wrapper around it, I would definitely call close before the dispose. Also if you don't address the comment to me, I probably won't see it.

Comment: @Yuriy Why would you call close. This is specifically about a MySql IDBConnection implementation, close is called for you when calling dispose. What you might be suggesting is that you want to close the connection, do some work and then reopen the connection.

Comment: @Bronumski the "MySql" part of the question was edited in later. I'm not disagreeing that close is called in the dispose of a SqlConnection. I am suggesting closing and reopening the connection. I just don't like how it seems Alio is saying it shouldn't be called inside a using nondiscriminatory.

Comment: @Yuriy I agree that you may want to close and then reopen. I am trying to think of a context where I might want to but even if I did I don't think I would use a using block. Prehaps I would wrap the whole thing up in something else and make that IDisposable. As I said it is hard to think of a senario.

Comment: @Aliostad: While it's not uncommon for `Close` and `IDisposable.Dispose` to be identical, it's also common for them to be subtly different.  Among other things, it is common for `Close` methods to promise to either send all pending data successfully or throw an exception; `IDisposable.Dispose` methods by contrast will often silently abandon data that cannot be sent (`Dispose` is often called while the stack is being unwound for an exception--a context where throwing a new exception would generally be bad).  The combination of `using` and `Close` will mean that...

Comment: ...a failure to send all pending data will result in an exception being thrown in those cases, and only those cases, where it would not overwrite another pending exception.  Omitting the `using` would mean that an exception before the close would leave the connection dangling; omitting the `Close` would mean that data loss while trying to close the connection would go undetected.  Note that stifling the exception on `Dispose` likely won't hurt, since the already-pending exception will let the application know that something probably prevented everything from being written.

Comment: @supercat agreed. That is why either you use "using" or you use try/finally and close. I personally would use try/finally/close. Same pattern applies to WCF.

Comment: @Aliostad: Even if you use try/finally/close, there's still the problem that if `Close` throws an exception it should be allowed to propagate *unless an exception was already pending*.  One could use a flag to indicate whether the `try` block was executed successfully, and call `Close` directly if it did, or wrapped within a try/catch block if it didn't, but that seems hokier than combining `Close` and `Using`.  I wish there was a `keep using x;` statement that, if placed within a `using` block, would cancel the `Dispose` on the object in question; that could make things cleaner.

Comment: @supercat what I mean is the known pattern of try/finally and then abort or close depending on the status of the state property.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the connection. Many close themselves in the Dispose method. SQLConnection for example closes itself in the Dispose.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's reasonable to suppose that an object implementing `IDisposable` should clean up its own resources and not require the close. Now it might not close as quickly as you might want, so you would manually close them yourself, but then you wouldn't use the `using` syntax.

Comment: Closing a connection from inside a using block, basically "degrades" it to a shorthand for try ... finally.

Answer (score 0):

It's not needed, as IDbConnection is specified as closing on Dispose().

(Strictly, it's specified as releasing resources on Dispose(), but that amounts to calling close. If some sort of db connection didn't take any resources then it wouldn't have to, but then that wouldn't be an issue anyway).

It can however be useful to call close prior to that, as the sooner connection objects are closed the better, but the `using` can catch early escape from the block (whether by an exception or, e.g. returning early in certain cases).

As a rule, it's good to keep the using blocks nice and tight, which removes the advantage, but there can be exceptions.