# C# ODP.net Dispose with using statement

Tags: c#, oracle

With ODP.net can you utilize the "using" statements within C# to dispose of commands, connections, etc or do you have to call them directly yourself? We are upgrading some apps from the older System.Data.OracleClient to ODP.net and I was just curious about the using statments.

Thanks all,

S

Comment: what happens when you try it and compile?

Comment: Please what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Oracle DB Provider implements the standard Db* classes you should be able to use the using statements. The only requirement for using the 'using' statement is that the class must implement the IDisposable interface which is implemented by each of the base classes. Their specific implementation may not perform the proper cleanup though so beware.

Comment: Thanks @M.Babcock...that is what I am worried about is proper cleanup.

Comment: Their library is closed source so you can attempt to get them to discuss the topic with you or you can do some memory profiling on your own to prove one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need those dispose commands if you are using "using" block.

See also:

[Best Practices for Using ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

[Using Statement (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[Closing connections within a using block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068705/closing-connections-within-a-using-block)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

By adopting using, you don't need to call .Dispose manually (as that's what using will do for you).

In fact, you should prefer the using construct, as that guarantees to run dispose even in exceptional cases.